# No Ethernet connection on Ubuntu Desktop 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla)

Tags: networking, network-manager, 20.10, lspci

Installing Ubuntu 20.10, but do not have any network other than Wi-Fi.
Please, can anyone assit me to find the root cause to use a nic ???

- there is no /etc/network/interfaces file
- /etc/resolv.conf contains

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

- sudo lshw -class network shows the following lines

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: f8:e4:e3:81:e0:f2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-31-generic firmware=55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-55.u ip=10.0.0.69 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:53514000-53517fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:53300000-5330ffff memory:53310000-53313fff
```

- lspci show the following lines

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b33 (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode]
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1b.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b8 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06bc (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0685
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117 [GeForce GTX 1650] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 05)
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
```

thanks in advance.

Regards Rainer

Comment: Since 18.04 Ubuntu does not use /etc/network/interface but rather /etc/netplan/. Also /etc/resolv.conf has changed, it is pointing to a local DNS which then refers to upstream.

Comment: can anyone send me the download of MrGoldWatch? I tried to download from realtek, but do get any captcha code via email ...